# How to get number of days. Data type error. Python

Tags: python, pandas

I need to extract number of days **(data['date'])-today ** to be exact.

I am using below formula

```
((docrcvd['Date of First Show Cause'].astype('datetime64[D]')))- date.today()
```

which is generating the following error. Please help.

```
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'DatetimeIndex' and 'datetime.date'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `pd.Timestamp`:

```
pd.to_datetime(docrcvd['Date of First Show Cause']) - pd.Timestamp('today')
```

If need days use [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html)   and [`Timestamp.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.floor.html):

```
(pd.to_datetime(docrcvd['Date of First Show Cause']).dt.floor('d') - 
 pd.Timestamp('today').floor('d'))
```

I think error means in some version of pandas for subtract from datetimes is necessary also same type datetimes, if is used `date`s it raise error.

Comment: It works. Thanks. Can you please explain it for my learning.